# Update json file in android assets folder

Tags: android, json, android-assets

I visualize my app's data using google charts in the html file kept in assets folder of my android app. The html file is loaded in android WebView.

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to silently update my android app's data.

Since the app needs to work offline too i need to persist the data. I can save it in shared preferences but i don't see a way for my javascript in html file to read android's shared preferences.

So, when the payload is received i want to update a .json file (in the assets folder) and wondering how to go about.

**JSON:**

```
[[a,b,c] , [1, 12, 24], [2, 45, 46]]
```

**Payload:**

```
[[a,0,1,53]]
```

**Updated JSON:**

```
[[a,b,c], [53, 12, 24], [2, 45, 46]]
```

*first element in the second array is updated from 1 to 53*

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 4):

> So, when the payload is received i want to update a .json file (in the assets folder)

That is not possible. Assets are read-only at runtime.

What you can do is write your new JSON to a file (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). Then, adjust your logic that reads in the JSON to look for the file first, falling back to the asset if the file is not available.

Comment: @LakshmanPilaka: If by "old file" you mean the asset, then no. Assets are read-only at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `assets` folder on your development machine is packaged into your APK file when you compile and release your app. On the device at run time, all resources in the `assets` folder are read-only because they are loaded from the installed APK. If you want to store data on the machine, then you need to either use a SQLite database or write a local file. See [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in the Android Developer Documentation for more details.